# Writing hierarchical data of nested lists and structs into an Apache Orc file

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hierarchical-data, orc

What's the correct way to write hierarchical data with optional and repeated fields into an Orc file?

The data is a list of JSON objects.  Each object has an ID and a hierarchical path to a DOM element.  Each DOM element has an optional tag and list of classes:

```js
{id: 1, hierarchy: [
    {tag: "div", lasses: ["blue", "red"]}, 
    {tag: "p"}
]}

{id: 1, hierarchy: [
    {tag: "nav", classes: ["green"]}, 
    {classes: ["red"]}
]}
```

The schema in Orc (Java) looks like:

```java
TypeDescription rootSchema = createStruct();
rootSchema.addField("id", createInt());
TypeDescription domElementSchema =
    createStruct()
        .addField("tag", createString())
        .addField("classes", createList(createString()));
// First list because 1 hierarchy per JSON object. 
// Second list because each hierarchy has multiple DOM elements.
rootSchema.addField("hierarchy", createList(createList(domElementSchema)));
```

I'm confused on how to set the [offsets](https://orc.apache.org/api/hive-storage-api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/exec/vector/MultiValuedColumnVector.html#offsets) and [lengths](https://orc.apache.org/api/hive-storage-api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/exec/vector/MultiValuedColumnVector.html#lengths) for the [ListColumnVector](https://orc.apache.org/api/hive-storage-api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/exec/vector/ListColumnVector.html) for the nested lists.  The code I have so far looks like:

```java
private static void writeJsonToOrcFile(TypeDescription schema) {
  VectorizedRowBatch batch = schema.createRowBatchV2();

  var ids = (LongColumnVector) batch.cols[0];
  var hierarchies = (ListColumnVector) batch.cols[1];
  var domElems = (ListColumnVector) hierarchies.child;
  var domElemStructs = (StructColumnVector) domElems.child;
  var tags = (BytesColumnVector) domElemStructs.fields[0];
  var classesList = (ListColumnVector) domElemStructs.fields[2];
  var classes = (BytesColumnVector) classesList.child;

  int hierarchiesOffset = 0;
  int classesOffset = 0;

  for (Map<String, JsonNode> jsonNode : JsonSource.forPath("my-data.json")) {
    // The current row.
    int row = batch.size++;

    // Write object ID
    ids.vector[row] = jsonNode.get("id").asLong();

    JsonNode hierarchy = jsonNode.get("hierarchy");
    hierarchies.offsets[row] = hierarchiesOffset;
    hierarchies.lengths[row] = hierarchy.size();

    // Associate offsets for DomElements
    for (int i = 0; i < hierarchy.size(); i++) {
      // Each item of the DomElements maps to a single struct.
      domElems.offsets[row + i] = row + i;
      domElems.lengths[row + i] = 1;
    }
    if (hierarchy.size() == 0) {
      domElems.offsets[row] = row;
      domElems.lengths[row] = 0;
      domElems.noNulls = false;
      domElems.isNull[row] = true;
    }

    // Write tags
    for (JsonNode domElement : hierarchy) {
      JsonNode tag = domElement.get("tag");
      if (tag == null) {
        tags.isNull[row] = true;
        tags.noNulls = false;
      } else {
        tags.setVal(row, tag.asText().getBytes());
      }
    }

    // Write classes
    int domElemIndex = 0;
    for (JsonNode domElement : hierarchy) {
      JsonNode classesNode = domElement.get("classes");
      classesList.offsets[row + domElemIndex] = classesOffset;
      classesList.lengths[row + domElemIndex] = classesNode.size();

      for (JsonNode classNode : classesNode) {
        String cssClass = classNode.asText();
        classes.setVal(row, cssClass.getBytes());
        classesOffset += 1;
      }

      hierarchiesOffset += 1;
      domElemIndex += 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Is this approach correct?

- `hierarchies` uses offsets into `domElems` based on the length of the hierarchy array.
- `domElems` has a one-to-one mapping with `domElemStructs`.
- `classesList` uses the row plus the `domElementIndex` for offsets into the `classes` vector.